# Can use BT socket from activity main to activity two?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have bluetooth connection in activity main. Can I use this connection in my 2nd activity?

When I launch the program, I am showing the table with the Bluetooth connection. After connecting to Bluetooth, I then show the main activity and I can send data, but I would like create second activity and send data. Is it possible?

```
package com.led.led;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;


public class ledControl extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btnROn,btnGOn,btnBOn,btnRGOn,btnRBOn,btnGBOn,btnRGBOn,btnWOn,btnOffAll,btnWOff;
    Button btnS0,btnS1,btnS2,btnL0,btnL1,btnL2, btnOpenScrollBar;

    SeekBar brightnessR,brightnessG,brightnessB,brightnessW;
    String address = "0123";
    byte[] BTData2 = new byte[2];
    byte[] BTData4 = new byte[4];
    byte[] BTData6 = new byte[6];
    byte[] BTData8 = new byte[8];

    private ProgressDialog progress;
    BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
    BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private boolean isBtConnected = false;
    //SPP UUID. Look for it
    static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent newint = getIntent();
        address = newint.getStringExtra(DeviceList.EXTRA_ADDRESS); //receive the address of the bluetooth device

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_led_control);


        brightnessB = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBarB);
        brightnessW = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBarW);

        new ConnectBT().execute(); //Call the class to connec
```